# Converting from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0 init Error

Tags: ios, swift2

I am trying to convert my project from swift 1.2 to swift 2.0
initially my method was something like this (Swift 1.2)

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}
```

after converting (Swift 2.0):

```
required init?;?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}
```

I am getting `Expected '(' for initializer parameters`. Any changes?

Comment: mine also wants to keep adding the ```;?``` after the ```?```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check if there is any syntax error in your code? I believe this one should work:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```